# Dojo instances of same widgets are not saparated

Tags: dojo, widget, declare

I have built a Dojo Widget for creating a list by entering values. the widget code is:

`define(["dojo/_base/declare", "dijit/_WidgetBase", "dijit/_TemplatedMixin", 'dojo/text!apps/orders/templates/multiAddList.html', "dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/dom-class", "dojo/query", "dijit/focus"],`

```
function (declare, WidgetBase, TemplatedMixin, html, dom, on, domConstruct, domClass, query, focusUtil) {

    return declare([WidgetBase, TemplatedMixin], {

        templateString: html,

        postCreate: function () {
            this.inherited(arguments);
            var that = this;
        },

        _checkIfEnter: function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                this._addUser();
            }
        },

        _addUser: function () {
            domClass.remove(this.ulAdded, "hidden");
            var textToAdd = this.userTextToAdd.value;
            var li = domConstruct.create("li", {}, this.ulAdded);
            domConstruct.create("span", {innerHTML: textToAdd}, li);
            var spanX = domConstruct.create("span", {class: 'icon-x right'}, li);
            this.itemsArray.push(textToAdd);
            this.userTextToAdd.value = "";
            focusUtil.focus(this.userTextToAdd);
            var that = this;
            on(spanX, "click", function () {
                domConstruct.destroy(li);
                that.itemsArray.splice(that.itemsArray.indexOf(textToAdd), 1);
                if (that.itemsArray.length == 0) {
                    domClass.add(that.ulAdded, "hidden");
                }
            });
        },

        itemsArray: []

    });
});
```

It is all OK. However - when I instantiate it twice on same dialog like this:

```
allowedDomains = new MultiAddList();
allowedDomains.placeAt(dom.byId('allowedDomains'), 0);
pdlEmails = new MultiAddList();
pdlEmails.placeAt(dom.byId('pdlEmails'), 0);
```

and then asking for allowedDomains.itemsArray() or pdlEmails.itemsArray() - I get the same list (as if it is the same instance) - althought in the UI presentation - he adds the list items separately and correctly.

Obviously, I am doing something wrong although I followed Dojo examples.

Does anyone know what I should do in order to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you make a dojo class using declare, object and array members are static, meaning they are shared across instances, so I would suggest doing `itemsArray: null` and then `this.itemsArray = []` in the `constructor` or `postCreate` somewhere.

Everything else looks fine, although I too would have a preference for using `hitch`, your solution is perfectly fine.

Comment: The relevant dojo docs for this behavior can be found at http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/_base/declare.html#id6 under the heading `Arrays and Objects as Member Variables`

Comment: thanks! =) always useful to back stuff up with a link, sorry I was too lazy originally.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for just giving you a hint, but you might want to look at the dojo.hicth()-function, as an alternative to the "this-that" contruction

```
on(spanX, "click", dojo.hitch(this, function () {
            domConstruct.destroy(li);
            this.itemsArray.splice(this.itemsArray.indexOf(textToAdd), 1);
            if (this.itemsArray.length == 0) {
                domClass.add(this.ulAdded, "hidden");
            }
        }));
```

The on-construct is a good one, but just testing this kind of construct might tell you whether that is the problem or not.

```
_addUser: function () {
    .....
    .....
    dojo.connect(spanX, "click", this, this.spanClicked);
    or
    dojo.connect(spanX, "click", dojo.hitch(this, this.spanClicked);
},
spanClicked: function(args) {
    domConstruct.destroy(li); //need to keep some reference to li
    this.itemsArray.splice(this.itemsArray.indexOf(textToAdd), 1);
    if (that.itemsArray.length == 0) {
        domClass.add(this.ulAdded, "hidden");
    }
}
```

Comment: I know what is dojo hitch. However - I am not sure it will solve this issue - although it is a better practice. Are you sure that context confustion is causing my problem?

Comment: Actually I thing it is the on function you need to hitch-up. I'll try to edit my response...