# Reference type values and initialization

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm not a guru at JS. Today I was told during a code review that for the following code below, Reference type values need to be initialized in the constructor which means change this somehow referring to the constraints: {}

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/form/CurrencyTextBox",
    "xxxx/util/currencyUtil",
    "./_InputWidgetMixin",
    "../secure/_SecureWidgetMixin"
],
    function (declare, xxxTextBox, xxxUtil, _InputWidgetMixin, _SecureWidgetMixin) {

        return declare("xxx.widget.input.xxxTextBox", [xxxTextBox, _InputWidgetMixin, _SecureWidgetMixin], {

            constraints: {},

            reset: function () {
                this._set("value", this.resetValue);
            },
```

not sure what this means and why I need to move this and if it's a Dojo thing or plain JS thing to worry about and why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say this is a dojo thing, it's to do with how dojo implements a class-like system. To understand why this is important, take a look at this recent question : [Dojo instances of same widgets are not saparated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635736/dojo-instances-of-same-widgets-are-not-saparated).

As mentioned there, arrays and objects are shared across instances, so if you don't want this behaviour, you should initialize them in your constructor. [Dojo docs on declare](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/_base/declare.html#id6)

Comment: thanks a lot!  Just one of the MANY things to learn about Dojo (gotchas).

Answer (score 1):

Your constraints will be a shared object across all instances of xxxTextBox unless in your constructor you assign a new object to constraints:

this.constraints = {};

This is because the constraints value is part of a prototype object and therefore this is a javascript thing.  Once you assign this.constraints you obscure the reference to the shared constraints with the objects own local copy.